# Can I add elements to a Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic

I want to know how I can make a Java program where an unknown amount of objects can be added to a GUI depending on user input. I can program in objects one at a time within the program, but I haven't seen a more dynamic program.

Can I do that with Java? If not, what can I do it with?

For more information, here's a picture.

[image]

There can be more than one question per question block, and each question can have it's own question block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse you can do it with Java Swings. All you gotta do is based on user input you gotta take a decision to add new JPanels. From the picture you've given in the example, you would need to add a Q&A block dynamically. Simply attach that to any event handler within your application so that it gets added dynamically

```
public getQandAPanel(){
    JPanel questPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel wrappingPanel = new JPanel();
    wrappingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    //CODE TO DECORATE question and answer panels should go here
    wrappingPanel.add(questPanel);
    wrappingPanel.add(answerPanel);
}
```

Now everytime when you call this getQandAPanel, this would return you a fresh JPanel everytime which you can add it to your parent JFrame. You should have a good idea of [Java Swings](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing-tutorial.htm) to know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can dynamically add and remove components. The basic code would be:

```
panel.add( ... );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```